# Is it possible to set UILineBreakMode or equivalent for title of UIViewController?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to set a UILineBreakMode for the title of a UIViewController?

It seems from the documentation that title is simply an NSString property, so it's not possible to set it directly. I'm assuming that somewhere behind the scenes the framework creates a UILabel with the title string as it's text - is it possible to access this UILabel in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this piece of code:

```
UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40)];
titleLabel.text = @"This is a very long long long string. I think this should do it";
titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel;
[titleLabel release];
titleLabel = nil;
```

You can adjust the parameters within to make it appear as you want.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API for accessing the `UILabel` that the framework creates.  However, you can set `myViewController.navigationItem.titleView` to a `UILabel` that you create yourself, with whatever properties you want.